# Alert each new candle how can i have just one alert

Tags: pine-script

Another problem on the same script.

I have add alert and i hope that i receive a alert only when changing color but no ... i receive each new candle.

How is it possible to have alert only when the color changing ?

```
study("v 2", overlay=true)

varLo = input(title="Fast (Conversion) Line", type=integer, defval=9, minval=1, maxval=99999)
varHi = input(title="Slow (Base) Line", type=integer, defval=26, minval=1, maxval=99999)
emafreq = input(title="Ema on price frequency", type=integer, defval=2, minval=1, maxval=99999)

a = lowest(varLo)
b = highest(varLo)
c = (a + b ) / 2

d = lowest(varHi)
e = highest(varHi)
f = (d + e) / 2

//g = ((c + f) / 2)[varHi]
//h = ((highest(varHi * 2) + lowest(varHi * 2)) / 2)[varHi]

z = ema(close, emafreq)

bggreen = (z > c and z > f)
bgred = (z < c and z < f)

bgcolor(bggreen ? green : bgred ? red : na)
alertcondition(condition=bggreen, title="Buy", message="green buy")
alertcondition(condition=bgred, title="Sell", message="red sell")
plot(z, title="ema on Price", color=black)
plot(c, title="Fast (Conversion) Line", color=green)
plot(f, title="Slow (Base) Line", color=red)
```

I want just one alert when it's a "new" green or a "new" red.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you tie your condition to the background color. So, it will become `true` on multiple bars.

What you need to do is, check if the color changed on the current bar. So, check if it was not green on the previous bar AND if it is green on the current bar.

```
is_new_green = not bggreen[1] and bggreen
is_new_red = not bgred[1] and bgred

bgcolor(bggreen ? green : bgred ? red : na)
alertcondition(is_new_green, title="Buy", message="green buy")
alertcondition(is_new_red, title="Sell", message="red sell")
```